# How to training/testing without make all of the data float32 in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to do image recognition, so I looked at [the CIFAR10](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py) example of Keras.

Before fitting the model to the data, the data (`X_train`/`X_test`) needs to be normalize to 0-1 and converted to `float32`. That's OK when I am using a small data like a CIFAR10.  But when the data size increases, it would consume a large amount of memory to convert the data to `float32`. I do not want to convert all the data to `float32`.

Can this work (convert data to `float32` and normalize) for each mini-batch in keras?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the conversion once and store the normalized, converted data to a file which you load for training, this way you don't need to convert it every time.

For example (`normalize.py` / python 3):

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10
import pickle

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

with open('cifar10_normalized.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(((X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)), f)
```

In your code (e.g. `train.py`) you can then do

```
import pickle

with open('cifar10_normalized.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = pickle.load(f)
```

Another possibility is to do the normalization and conversion for each batch. Use [`model.train_on_batch`](http://keras.io/models/model/#train_on_batch) to run a single batch. For example:

```
for (x_train,y_train) in yourData:
    x_train = x_train.astype(np.float32) / 255
    model.train_on_batch(x_train, y_train)
```

Finally you can also [use a python generator for training](http://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator):

```
def g():
    for (x_train,y_train) in yourData:
        x_train = x_train.astype(np.float32) / 255
        yield (x_train, y_train)
model.fit_generator(g)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.  I did change only part of "yourData" to "(X_train,Y_train)" at example of yield. And I got an error when use the function that  "model.fit_generator(g)" . Is my way wrong? If I'm doing Absurdity, sorry.

Comment: `yourData` would be something like `[(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)]`, not `(X_train,Y_train`). This is basic python, I cannot help you with that.